# Simple autonomous ODE perturbed by a constant coefficient

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ODEs
\begin{equation}
y'=f(y), y(0)=y_0
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
y'=a f(y), y(0)=y_0
\end{equation}
where $f$ is Lipschitz. Let $y_1(t)$ ($y_2(t)$) be the unique solution of the first (second) ODE.
Can I conclude that $y_1(at)=y_2(t)$?

**My attempt**. I should verify that
\begin{align}
\frac{d y_1(at)}{dt} = a f(y_1(at))
\end{align}
that is true if and only if 
\begin{align}
\frac{d y_1(at)}{d(at)} = f(y_1(at))
\end{align}
that is true if and only if 
\begin{align}
\frac{d y_1(x)}{d(x)} = f(y_1(x))
\end{align}
which is true because $y_1$ is a solution of the first ODE. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z(t):=y_1(at)$. Then $z'(t)=ay_1'(at)=af(y_1(at))=af(z(t))$ and $z(0)=y_0$.

Hence $z$ is a solution of the second initial value problem. Since the solution of this initial value problem is unique, we have $z=y_2$.